# php and moving images to new folders

Tags: php, image, copy, directory, rename

I have an image in my `templates` folder that is made using php with a background template `.jpg` (stored in the same folder) and some text submitted from a form. It is saved as a jpg in this folder. I want to copy the php-constructed image to a folder `uploads`, and then rename it as `image451.jpg`, or whatever the id number is. I think I should use the `copy()` and `rename()` php functions, but I can't get them to work. How do I do this?

Comment: "can't get them to work" is pretty vague. Can you post the code you are using, and tell us the specific errors or unexpected behaviors you have encountered?

Comment: When you say "I can't get them [`copy()` and `rename()`] to work," what do you mean? How are they *not* working?

Answer (score 3):

You will need to be sure that your web server has write access to the `uploads` directory where you want them to reside.  Then you can just do:

```
if (!rename("oldfilename.jpg", "/path/to/uploads/image451.jpg"))
{
  echo "oops, something went wrong moving your file.";
}
```

We don't know what server platform you're running so I can't be specific on how to check directory write permissions unless you add that info to your question.

Comment: @webmachine, @Oscar M's  answer is far more complete. Use his instead!

Answer (score 2):

You should test if your destination is writeable before trying to move the new file there.

```
$dest_dir = "/path/to/uploads/";
$src_file = "path/to/orig/file.jpg";
if (is_writeable($dest_dir)) {
    $dest_file = $dest_dir . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . basename($src);
    if (false == rename($src, $dest_file)) {
        trigger_error('Could not move file', E_USER_ERROR);
    }
}
else {
    trigger_error('Destination dir is not writeable', E_USER_WARNING);
}
```